# Script PowerShell if statement in Foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I am seeking PowerShell expert out there with some help to solve small issue with my looping statement.

I am having an issue with my syntax at line "__site1 -Name Value -Value http://server1:1234/bfmirror/downloads/}".
when the below foreach statement equal to "true", "http://server1" supposed to set changes in the windows 10 registry to "http://server2", "http://server3" and so on.

Below is an illustration of what I am trying to do.

```
$list = @("server1", "server2", "server3")  # Example list of servers

foreach ($item in $list) {
    $result = Test-NetConnection $item -Port 1234 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TcpTestSucceeded

    if ($result -eq $true) {Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Client\__site1 -Name Value -Value http://server1:1234/bfmirror/downloads/}
}
```

---

I have tried the below method but it still failed.

```
$list | ForEach-Object {
    $Result = Test-NetConnection $_ -Port 1234 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TcpTestSucceeded

    if ($_ -eq 'True') {Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Client\__site1 -Name Value -Value http://$_:1234/bfmirror/downloads/
```

---

I also tried changing the below if statement but still failed.

```
if ($_ -eq 'True') {Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Client\__site1 -Name Value -Value http://'$_':1234/bfmirror/downloads/
```

Comment: Change 'True' to $True

Comment: Please correctly [format your post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Your comparing against the wrong variable. Try `($result -eq 'True')` or even as @jdweng says use `$true` instead of `true` but it will yield the same result.

Comment: Simply test with `if ($result) {...}`, but anyway.. What do you mean by _failed_ ? Any error messages? If so, please add these **in full** by [edit]ing your post